# Wifi is disconnecting after connecting for few seconds and not able to connect it again

Tags: wireless, networking, kubuntu

I downloaded Kubuntu 13.10 on my HP 2202 laptop and the wifi on it doesn't work. I'm running it in parallel with Windows 8, and the wifi works find on Windows (as it has always done), but in Kubuntu it connects for some time (after restart of PC) and it will disconnect. But it's showing the wifi network after it disconnects. If you enter the password again, it also won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel is 3.11, your only solution for the wifi is to upgrade the kernel. 
I had the same exact problem when i was able to connect, then all of a sudden it disconnects, when i disable and enable it connects then it disconnects. so it was was fixed when i upgraded the kernel to 3.12.

Download it from here
http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/

Comment: Hi,Thanks, I upgraded to 3.14 and its working fine now.